# ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup() vs ReactDOM.render()

Tags: reactjs

According to the documentation on Reactjs:

[ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) is to be used typically on the server-side. So something like [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) but I see a lot of Stack Overflow answers that use `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()` on the client-side.

On the other hand, [ReactDOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#overview) says `DOM-specific methods that can be used at the top level of your app`.

So my question is should I use `ReactDOM.render()` instead of `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()` on the client-side in one of my non top-level components?

What's a good practice and why?